# Using different Databases in the same Application with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My applicacion is accesed by mutiple tenants each of these tenants have their own Database which are allocated on the same MongoDB Cluster and have the exact same colollections Schemas just different Dbs Names of each other

I have read the documentation of mongoose.useDB() and trying their example however i havent been able to succed, each time i use mongoose.useDb() no data is retrived from the server

this is my main conection string maked on app.js

```
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true },{server: {poolSize: 100}})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB.');
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

One of my Schema Files Schema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username:{type:String},
    password:{type:String},
}, {collection:'usuarios'})

  
module.exports= (postSchema);
```

And this is the controller request

```
const Parametros = require('../models/parametros')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.get('/api/parametros/', async (req, res) => {

      const db = mongoose.connection.useDb(req.params.id,{useCache: true});
      const Parametros1 = db.model('Parametros', Parametros);

// I register the model since the documentation says i have to, but I don't understand why 
//when I change my database I need to register all my schemas again, if when 
//I create a direct connection to a specific database I don't have to do it, all the collections already listed appear

          const query = Parametros.find(this)

          query.exec().then(
              (result) => {
                  res.status(200).send(result)
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                  res.json(err);
              });
})
```

The collection of parameters in the Master database is full of data, however when I use useDb() even registering the model as it comes in the documentation it returns without data, and yet if I use mongoose.connection(url) I can perform the same query without registering the model without any problem and the data it returns is correct.

im trying to implement this useDb() approach since on production multiple client will trigger the same endpoint but all will be to a diferent database and my application trows an error when trying to connect twice since theres already an open conection (i dont know if this is just because im testing on local).

Another Approach i try, was to connect to the database on each request and closing it after query the result from the collection however with this approeach my application sends an error when trying to close the connection

Creating and closing connection after request approach:

```
function mongooseConnection(hotel) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const db = mongoose.connect(url + hotel, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then((conn) => {
        resolve(conn);
      })
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    })
  }

exports.getParametros = async (req, res) => {

    if (req.query.id != 'undefined') {

            const conn = await mongooseConnection(req.query.id)

            if(conn){
                const query = Parametros.find(this)

                query.exec().then(
                    (result) => {
                        res.status(200).send(result)
                    }).then(
                        ()=>{
                            mongoose.connection.close()
                        })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        res.json(err);
                    });
            }
    }
}
```

However this trows and error when it reaches the mongoose.connection.close() stating "pool is draining, new operations forbidden"

So i have two questions

1. What am i doing wrong on the useDB() approach
2. On  the second approach how can i create a connection and close it after i query the result without any error, this considering more
   clients will be accesing same endpoint and trying to connect at
   diferent databases

Comment: Is the api request sent after you see `Connected to MongoDB.` from `mongoose.connect`?